# Which Intermediate operation in Mono will not skip to next intermediate operation in Reactive programming?

Tags: spring-webflux, reactive-programming

I have a problem statement where I am calling another service from the main service and the doOnNext() operation is not giving the desired result. The current doOnNext() operation calls the other service which inturn has ASYNC flatmap operation happening and then the map operation is being called.
It skips to the next intermediate operation.
I want to use an intermediate operation over my Mono object which will complete the ASYNC calls to flatmap and will then move to the next operation.

Could anyone please suggest anything?
I am new to Reactive programming.

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing the code

Comment: applicationService.getApplicationID(id).doOnNext(a->customerService.validateID(a.getID())).Map();   
Here the function call inside doOnNext() is not yielding the desired result. This call should throw an error when I run it . However , The subsequent internal calls are giving the issue.

Comment: Can you please update the question with the code? I mean put it not in the comments but in the question itself. So far it looks like you use `doOnNext` to some processing, which is not supposed to work this way. For processing you usually do `map` or `flatMap`

Comment: Thank you Igor . it worked with flatmap.